# How can I set the number of signs after comma for the "FLOAT" attribute in SQL "CREATE TABLE" query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have got this code right now:

```
CREATE TABLE DISC_KR4
(KodDysc TEXT (4),
NazvDysc TEXT (80), 
NomTrym INTEGER, 
NomKurs INTEGER, 
ObsDysCred FLOAT);
```

I need ObsDysCred to have only 1 sign after comma. How do I set that in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to use DECIMAL

```
ObsDysCred DECIMAL(18, 1)
```

Comment: what does 18 mean?

Comment: 18 is the precision, the total number of digits that can be stored, both to the left and right of the decimal point

1 is the scale, the maximum number of digits that can be stored to the right of the decimal separator

Comment: Got it, but when I try writing DECIMAL(18, 1) instead of FLOAT, I get a syntax error

Comment: CREATE TABLE DISC_KR4
(KodDysc TEXT (4),
NazvDysc TEXT (80), 
NomTrym INTEGER, 
NomKurs INTEGER, 
ObsDysCred DECIMAL(18,1));

Comment: Copied + pasted it. Result - syntax error. I am working in MS Access 2010, maybe this has something to do with the error.

Comment: I guess you are using DAO, which you not mentioned in your OP. If so, there is no chance to use a decimal field, it was not supported by DAO. You must use ADO, CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "CREATE TABLE DISC_KR4 " & _
"(KodDysc TEXT (4), " & _
"NazvDysc TEXT (80), " & _
"NomTrym INTEGER, " & _
"NomKurs INTEGER, " & _
"ObsDysCred DECIMAL(18,1));"